# R - regular expression, match after second or third occurence

Tags: r, regex, match

I have a vector of character strings:
`x <- c(
"\nFolsom Field, University of Colorado, Boulder, CO (9/3/72)",
"\nHollywood Palladium, Hollywood, CA (9/9/72)"
)`

And I want to extract event location, city, state, and date. I have figured out the event location, city, and date, but cannot correctly match the state -- This issue I am having is that I need to match after the second or the third comma and before the first parentheses.

I tried: 
`stateLoc <- regexpr(",{2,}.+?\\(", x)
state <- regmatches(x, stateLoc)` but that returned an empty character vector.

Any input is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract these details using a single `str_match` call:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("\nFolsom Field, University of Colorado, Boulder, CO (9/3/72)","\nHollywood Palladium, Hollywood, CA (9/9/72)")
> res <- str_match(x, "\\s*([^,]*),\\s*([A-Z]+)\\s*\\(([0-9/]+)\\)")
> res[,2]
[1] "Boulder"   "Hollywood"
> res[,3]
[1] "CO" "CA"
> res[,4]
[1] "9/3/72" "9/9/72"
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/7vXhAK/1).

**Details**

- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^,]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than a comma
- `,` - a comma
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([A-Z]+)` - Capturing group 2: 1 or more uppercase letters
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\(` - a `(` char
- `([0-9/]+)` - Capturing group 3: 1 or more digits or slashes
- `\\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 1):

This regex worked for me

```
library(stringr)
x <- c(
  "\nFolsom Field, University of Colorado, Boulder, CO (9/3/72)",
  "\nHollywood Palladium, Hollywood, CA (9/9/72)",
  "\nThe Spectrum, Philadelphia, PA (5/1/2010) "
)

##String trim is just to cut trailing spaces
states <- str_trim(str_extract(x, "\\s[A-Z]{1,2}\\s"))
states
```

Comment: This is to match whitespace. The regex says match a whitespace, followed by two uppercase letters, followed by a whitespace

Comment: I just realized I have an issue matching the city. I matched between the 2nd & 3rd comma, but in the first element that matches `University of Colorado`, as such: `cityLoc <- regexpr(",.+?,", x) 
  city <- regmatches(x, cityLoc) %>% str_sub(3, -2)` Do you know what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Does the city always come before state?

Comment: Yes the city always comes before the state with a comma in between them, however there may exist cases where there is an additional space such as New York or San Francisco -- I apologize I didn't have that in my original vector.

Comment: str_remove(str_extract(x, "[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30},\\s[A-Z]{1,2}\\s|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}\\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30},\\s[A-Z]{1,2}\\s"),",\\s[A-Z]{1,2}\\s")


This regex worked for the cities